# Azure search scoring profile based result issue

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

This is my rating based scoring profile.

```
"scoringProfiles":{ "name": "ratings",
    "functions": [
        {
            "type": "magnitude",
            "fieldName": "rating",
            "boost": 10,
            "interpolation": "linear",
            "magnitude": {
                "boostingRangeStart": 1,
                "boostingRangeEnd": 10,
                "constantBoostBeyondRange": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Result that I got after search

```
RecID   Rating No.
 1      4.5
 2      4
 3      4
 4      5
```

Why RecID 4 and Rating No. 5 come at last place?

Comment: I'll need a bit more context to help. What was the search request? Did it include search keywords? Did you reference the scoring profile in it?

Comment: Here is my search request with search keyword and refer the scoring profile.
https://{0}/indexes/{1}/docs?api-version={2}&search=foods&searchFields=Restaurant&scoringProfile=ratings&$skip=50&$count=true

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that influence the score and ultimate sort order of items. Without looking at the dataset it's hard to tell, but here are a few things to consider.

While the scoring function will affect the score based on the "rating" field, the base score will be given by the relevance of the text match.

Relevance of the text match is calculated taking into account how common terms are within the document and across documents (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf for some background). If you had multiple words in your search, one thing that could have impacted ranking would be that some subset of the documents had a rare term in them. In your case you had a single term ("foods"), so the only aspect left that could have an impact is text length. In order to account for how individual terms get diluted over large phrases, term hits on shorter phrases are given higher scores than hits on longer phrases. On small datasets these subtleties tend to be more visible, and sometimes with scores are close having a few extra terms in one document than the other will cause it to go down in relevance.

Of course, it could also be an issue on our side.

Happy to drill more into details for your specific case. I would need more details on the dataset (# of documents, some samples of content, etc.), we could do it here or on private email if you'd rather not post the content publicly.